# Checking to see if an HTML table row element is empty

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am working on developing an html table using JavaScript and I am always creating three rows. However, there is a condition in which it creates two full rows and the last row is an empty row. How can I check to see if the last row is empty before adding it to my table? I do **NOT** want to add the row if it is empty.

```
 const element = document.getElementById("two_weeks");
 element.appendChild(tble_row);
 element.appendChild(tble_row2);
 element.appendChild(tble_row3);
```

Element is my HTML table and tble_row3 is an HTMLTableRowElement.

Comment: `!tble_row.cells.length` passes when a row is empty, i.e. there's no cells on the row. Chek `textContent` of the row, if there could be empty `td/th` elements.

Comment: How are you creating the ```tble_row3``` object ?

Comment: Hy can you please share HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoutout to @Teemu. He came up with the correct answer. This is what I did for it to work:

```
if (tble_row3.cells.length) {
     element.appendChild(tble_row3);
}
```

This correctly displays rows that have content and does **not** display rows that are empty.